# Laravel npm install getting warnings - npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs

Tags: php, node.js, laravel-5, npm

I'm new to Laravel, so I'd like some help please. I'm following the training from Laracasts on [how to manage css and js](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/6).

When I try to run `npm install` I get some warnings like

`npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported`

I also try to install gulp with `npm install --global gulp`, but I get this

```
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

so basically if I try to run the `gulp` command I get the `No command 'gulp' found` from the command line.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Just some additional info: I'm on vm Ubuntu 14.04 and my node.js and npm versions are:

```
node -v
v5.4.1

npm -v
3.3.12
```

[image]

This is the error I get when I try to run `npm install --global gulp`

[image]

Comment: check this out https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules` clearly indicates that the user you are running `npm install --global gulp` with has no write access to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. Please make sure you have the proper write permissions - as mentioned in the comments check https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: I chown the `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` like the video shows, but still the problem occurs. Here is my result form command line `drwxrwxr-x  6 lykourgos lykourgos 4096 May  8 13:04 gulp
drwxr-xr-x 11 lykourgos lykourgos 4096 May  8 12:07 npm
`

Comment: Can you please show us the complete output of `ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules` ? Just put a screenshot of it into your post.

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x  4 lykourgos root      4096 May  8 13:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 lykourgos root      4096 May  8 11:26 ..
drwxrwxr-x  6 lykourgos lykourgos 4096 May  8 13:11 gulp
drwxr-xr-x 11 lykourgos lykourgos 4096 May  8 12:07 npm
`

Comment: Did also upload a screenshot of it into the post

Comment: And you still get `npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules` when running `npm install --global gulp` ? Could you show us a screen of that as well?

Comment: or better yet, set the `prefix` in the `~/.npmrc` and don't mess with permissions outside your home directory

Answer (score 0):

Gulp is now installed on your system. You can find it under `/usr/local/bin/gulp`. The permission error is gone and the other stuff is only warning that did not stop gulp from working. You should be able to run `gulp` command now.

Comment: ok, I run the `gulp` command, and says `Fetching Sass Source Files...` and `Saves into ..`, but then I get an error and don't have this file `public/css/app.css` .. I have uploaded a screenshot.. is this because of the warnings?

Comment: Nevermind.. fixed it! it was a syntax error on my sass file, my bad!

Comment: just some additional information about the warnings.. could this couse any additional problem with anything else ? what if I need to run again the `npm install` command ?